# Android video playback 'Can't play this video'

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, h.264

Been reading through the stack posts and blogs on this and it seems like it should be easy, so perhaps I just need another pair (or few thousand pairs) of eyes.

Current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
   android:paddingLeft="2px"
   android:paddingRight="2px"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:paddingTop="2px"
   android:paddingBottom="2px"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

  <VideoView 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/VideoView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vid_splash);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);        
    videoView.setVideoPath("vid_splash.mp4");
    videoView.start();  
}
```

Just to get started with something working, I made this an activity (though it really should be in a fragment).  My main activity fires off an intent to start the activity with the above onCreate call.

The result is an activity that launches and quickly says:  "Can't play this video".

I have tested this with reference videos, the video in another stack overflow post called "documentariesandyou.mp4", etc.  I've re-encoded my video to make sure it's h.264 'baseline' profile, as well as several Handbrake Android profiles.

The result is always the same:  "Can't play this video".

The only error I'm seeing in the LogCat is as follows:

```
MediaPlayer  Error    (1, -2147483648)
```

Comment: are you sure path of your video is correct? this error can also occur is the path is not correct

Answer (score 0):

since the mediaplayer error code (1) represents (unknown error) so its very difficult to detect the problem. anyway, you can use `MediaPlayer` with a `SurfaceView` instead of `VideoView` to gain more control over the video. `VideoView` is a sub-class of `MediaPlayer`   you can find here http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your video to Android standards .
By using video converter program or online converter, you can convert your video file to Android .mp4 format.

As an example, you can convert with this site :

http://video.online-convert.com/convert-video-for-android

Comment: @Revenge You are right. We need to convert the video to an android supportable format.